# How to build an Entity Framework model from a PostgreSQL schema?

Tags: database, entity-framework, postgresql, npgsql

(This question follows [an excellent post on using Npgsql](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/ddex.html)).

I have a PostgreSQL (9.5.0) database with two schemas: public and nova. I then used NuGet console:

```
Install-Package EntityFramework6.Npgsql -Version 3.0.5
```

Now I add the following element to the `app.config` file:

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <remove invariant="Npgsql"/>
        <add name="Npgsql Data Provider"
             invariant="Npgsql"
             description=".Net Data Provider for PostgreSQL"
             type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7"
             support="FF" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Then I added a new "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" to my project.

The following connection properties were filled in:

```
Database:       chaos
Host:           localhost
Password:       psw
Port:           5432
Search Path:    nova
Username:       postgres
```

The connection is then tested and everything works.

The Entity Framework is then built with database first. The `.edmx` file is built correctly and the VS designer is happy.

The problem is the `.edmx` file is built from all the tables in the database. That is, both the public and nova schema's tables are in the `.edmx` file.

In addition to specifying the search path in the connection properties, I have tried the following on the database--but these do not change both schemas being added to the `.edmx` file:

- ALTER DATABASE chaos SET search_path TO nova;
- ALTER USER postgres SET search_path to nova;
- ALTER SCHEMA public RENAME TO public_old;

Is there any way to build the Entity Framework with only the one schema, `Nova`?

My components:

- Windows 10 Professional
- Entity Framework 6.0.0
- Npgsql 3.0.5
- PostgreSQL 9.5.0
- Visual Studio 2015

TIA

Comment: When you create the `.edmx` model file - can't you just select the objects from the `Nova` schema and leave out the others? (That's the way it would work in SQL Server - I don't know PostgreSQL so I can't say how it works there)

Comment: @marc_s  Yes...but it can be a little bit confusing since both schemas have at times the same file name, so a "1" is suffixed onto the duplicate file name. Also, the spec gives the impression that the connection can be schema specific...something I have not been able to do as yet.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Package Manager Console to run a Database First scaffolding.
Use the `-Schemas` parameter to only run it for specific schemas:

`Scaffold-DbContext "host=server;database=chaos;user id=postgres;" Devart.Data.PostgreSql.Entity.EFCore -Schemas nova`

The `Scaffold-DbContext` command also accepts a parameter for tables: `-Tables table1,table2`.

Answer taken from [here](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/docs/EFCore-Database-First.html).

See also [this](https://medium.com/@RobertKhou/getting-started-with-entity-framework-core-postgresql-c6fa09681624) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://www.npgsql.org/ef6/index.html) and quite bit research as I was working on similar problem, I found that with postgres using [npgsql](https://www.npgsql.org) it is only possible to get model generation via Database First approach in .NET core framework as also mentioned by [veuncent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45882588/9076566).

For Entity Framework 6 in .Net Framework there is **no option exist** as of today in [npgsql](https://www.npgsql.org/ef6/index.html).